# Apache is redirecting folder to file .html with the same name

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect 404 json fales to 404.json (with "{}" as content). But apache is redirecting folder to a html file with the same folder name and any custom 404.json redirect fails.

**File structure:**

- /example1/
- /example2/
- /example1.html
- /example2/data.json
- /data.json

**Working (redirect to 404.html):**

- http://example.com/example3/

**Working (redirect to 404.json):**

- http://example.com/not-exists.json
- http://example.com/example3/data.json
- http://example.com/example2/data.json

**Working (open the file):**

- http://example.com/example1.html
- http://example.com/data.json
- http://example.com/example2/ (list files in folder)

**Not working (default apache 404):**

- http://example.com/example1/
- http://example.com/example1/not-exists.json
- http://example.com/example2/not-exists.json

It seems apache is redirecting "example1/" to "example1.html", especially when I try to access a file inside the directory like http://example.com/example2/data.json, shows 404 message:

> *The requested URL /example2.html/data.json was not found on this server.*

It happens even without the .htaccess! All the problem because the example1.html file.

**htaccess:**

```
# Rewrite MOD
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# If requested resource exists as a file or directory go to it
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule (.*) - [L]

# 404 json
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)\.json$ 404.json [L]

# 404 page
RewriteRule . 404.html [L]
```

Maybe it is some apache file mapping configuration but I can't find anything about it. It happens only for deploy server, for localhost it's fine. =/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have it like this with `MultiViews` turned off:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# If requested resource exists as a file or directory go to it
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# 404 json
RewriteRule \.json$ 404.json [L,NC]

# 404 page
RewriteRule ^ 404.html [L]
```

Comment: OMG! It's so simple and I spent hours trying to fix it... thanks a lot!!

Comment: Thanks to fix entire .htaccess too =)