# Why Is Apache Returning 301 Redirect When Html File Name Is Same As Directory Name

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have this directory structure on my server:

```
+---subdir
|     |
|     +---page1
|     |     |  
|     |     +---en.html
|     |
|     +---page1.html 
|     |
|     +---page2.html
|
+---index.html
```

**Wanted behavior:** If I visit an URL which doesn't contain a file extension, add `.html` to the end of the URL and serve that file.

My `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  # prerendered html pages

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,4}
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L]

 # return index file by default
  
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

</IfModule>
```

**Actual behavior:**

If I wisit `test.com/subdir/page1/en`, the served file is `test.com/subdir/page1/en.html` - as expected.

If I wisit `test.com/subdir/page2`, the served file is `test.com/subdir/page2.html` - as expected.

If I wisit `test.com/subdir/page1`, I get a 301 redirect to `test.com/subdir/page1/` (adds slash to the end), which in terms serves me the file `test.com/index.html`

So it works OK for `page2`, but not for `page1`. The only difference is that for `page1` there is also a directory with the same name. Why am I getting a redirect in this case?

I also tried turning off `MultiViews`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39150376/2468620), but with no effect.

Comment: The trailing slash redirect is responsibility of mod_dir. You can turn it off via `DirectorySlash`, but read what consequences that can have carefully first.

Comment: Why do you have `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$` condition

Comment: @CBroe your comment helped. If you post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trailing slash redirect is responsibility of `mod_dir`. You can turn it off via the `DirectorySlash` directive, but read what consequences that can have carefully first.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash:

> Typically if a user requests a resource without a trailing slash, which points to a directory, mod_dir redirects him to the same resource, but with trailing slash for some good reasons:
>
> - The user is finally requesting the canonical URL of the resource
>   mod_autoindex works correctly. Since it doesn't emit the path in the link, it would point to the wrong path.
> - DirectoryIndex will be evaluated only for directories requested with trailing slash.
> - Relative URL references inside html pages will work correctly.